# Avoiding unnecessary database calls when converting JPA Entity to DTO in Spring Boot with GraphQL

Tags: spring-boot, graphql, graphql-java, spring-graphql

I am developing an application using Spring Boot and GraphQL. When returning an Entity directly from GraphQL, data fetchers automatically handle the queries, fetching only the tables requested in the GraphQL query.

For instance:

```
query Workspace {
    workspace {
        id
    }
}
```

This will only query the `workspace` table.

```
query Workspace {
    workspace {
        id
        users {
            id
        }
    }
}
```

This will query both the `workspace` and `user` tables.

However, when I return a DTO, because I explicitly call `getUsers` in my transformation logic, it fetches the users as well, leading to unnecessary database calls.

Here are my JPA Entities:

```
@Entity
public class Workspace {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "workspace", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<User> users;
}

@Entity
public class User {
    private String fullName;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Workspace workspace;
}
```

This is my service layer method:

```
public WorkspacePayload getWorkspace() {    
    Workspace workspace = workspaceRepository.findById(1L)    
                       .orElseThrow(() -> new GraphQLException("Workspace not found"));    
    return WorkspaceUtil.prepareWorkspacePayload(workspace);
}
```

And the transformation logic:

```
public WorkspacePayload prepareWorkspacePayload(Workspace workspace) {
    return WorkspacePayload.builder()
        .id(workspace.getId())
        .name(workspace.getName())
        .users(getUsers(workspace))
        .build();
}

private List<UserPayload> getUsers(Workspace workspace) {
    return workspace.getUsers().stream()
        .map(workspaceUser -> UserPayload.builder()
                            .id(workspaceUser.getId())
                            .fullName(workspaceUser.getFullName())
                            .build())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

My challenge: How can I optimize my service layer to ensure that I don't make unnecessary database queries when I want to return DTOs instead of entities? What is the best practice for this scenario?

Comment: Your current logic requires the users, so at some point you have to query the data from db.

Comment: Of course I have to question. However, I want to question it when I need it.

Comment: You have set FetchType.LAZY so you will query only when you will need it (aka when calling workspace.getUsers()).

Comment: Graphql Data Fetchers retrieve data regardless of the fetch.

Comment: So in your prepareWorkspacePayload, if you comment out .users(getUsers(workspace)), you still perform the fetch of users?

Comment: If you are using graphql it is true. If you want to example you can look this repo : https://github.com/fatihaksoy59/graphql-tekmer

Answer (score 0):

I think there is not the one right answer, because what you want to/what you need to query depends on the query. Enabling "lazy" fetching can be right (if user is not queries) but can be wrong (if user is part of the query).

To overcome this problem you have to deceide at runtime what is best behaviour.

First, you can get the list of requested fields in a concrete query from the [DataFetchingFieldSelectionSet](https://docs.spring.io/spring-graphql/docs/1.0.0-M3/reference/html/#controllers-schema-mapping-signature).

With that information you could tweak the behaviour of `prepareWorkspacePayload` and skip the `getUsers` call if the `users` field is not part of the current query.

In more complex situations you may habe to customize your DB query behaviour, for example by using an [EntityGraph](https://thorben-janssen.com/jpa-21-entity-graph-part-2-define/), that overrides the `fetchType` on an annotated attribute.
Depending on your database structure it might be even better to build custom queries and read custom ["DTO Projections"](https://thorben-janssen.com/dto-projections/) from your database that you then can use for for your GraphQL results.